# JavaFX: Cannot set font size programmatically after font being set by CSS

Tags: css, font-face, javafx, javafx-2

I have stored the default font type and size of my application in a CSS file which I apply using the code:

```
label.getStyleClass().add("labelStyleClass");
```

However I also added the feature that if the user provides its own preference, it should override the default settings (set above) and use the user provided font size:

```
double userSize = readFromFile;
label.setFont(new Font(userSize));
```

In this case the `label.setFont()` call does not set the new size given by user. When I comment out the initial CSS code, the later works.

Any workaround?

Note: cross-posted at [JavaFX forum](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2437387&stqc=true)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's by design. For architectural reasons chain of overrides for css works as follows:

> default caspian.css < API settings < user's `Scene` css < user's `Parent` css  < `setStyle()`

Here is the quote from [css reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introscenegraph):

> The JavaFX CSS implementation applies the following order of precedence; a style from a user agent style sheet has lower priority than a value set from code, which has lower priority than a Scene or Parent style sheet. Inline styles have highest precedence. Style sheets from a Parent instance are considered to be more specific than those styles from Scene style sheets.

Thus, you can achieve your goal by using `setStyle()` instead of an API call. Try to run the next example:

```
public void start(Stage stage) {
    VBox root = new VBox(10);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    // font.css: .labelStyleClass { -fx-font-size: 20 }
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("font.css").toExternalForm());

    root.getChildren().add(LabelBuilder.create().text("default").build());
    root.getChildren().add(LabelBuilder.create().text("font-css").styleClass("labelStyleClass").build());

    Label lblApi = LabelBuilder.create().text("font-css-api (doesn't work)").styleClass("labelStyleClass").build();
    lblApi.setFont(Font.font(lblApi.getFont().getFamily(), 40));
    root.getChildren().add(lblApi);

    Label lblStyle = LabelBuilder.create().text("font-css-setstyle (work)").styleClass("labelStyleClass").build();
    lblStyle.setStyle("-fx-font-size:40;");
    root.getChildren().add(lblStyle);

    stage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked ! Initially I was trying to override -fx-font: 14 "arial"; with setStyle(-fx-font-size: 28;) which did not work. But when I put the font size and style in separate lines like -fx-font-family: serif;     -fx-font-size: 14; in the css  and tried to override by setStyle(-fx-font-size: 28;) it worked.