# Validation using bindin

Tags: validation, javafx-2, fxml

I've made a configuration panel for a JavaFX application. I managed to create a dynamic change listener as follows:

```
public class InputMaskChecker implements ChangeListener<String> {

    public static final String NUMERIC      = "^[0-9]*$";
    public static final String TEXTONLY     = "^\\w*$";
    public static final String PASSWORD     = "^[\\w\\+\\!\\?\\-\\$\\&\\%£]+$";
    public static final String DATASOURCE   = "^([a-zA-Z]+:){3}@([a-zA-Z0-9]+:)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$";
    public static final String TCPPORT      = "^(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\\d|65[0-4]\\d\\d|6[0-4]\\d{3}|[1-5]\\d{4}|[2-9]\\d{3}|1[1-9]\\d{2}|10[3-9]\\d|102[4-9])$";

    private static final String STYLE = "-fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, red, 4, 0.0, 0, 0);";

    public final BooleanProperty erroneous = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    private final String mask;
    private final int max_lenght;
    private final TextField control;


    public InputMaskChecker(String mask, TextField control) {
        this.mask = mask;
        this.max_lenght = 0;
        this.control = control;
    }

    public InputMaskChecker(String mask, int max_lenght, TextField control) {
        this.mask = mask;
        this.max_lenght = max_lenght;
        this.control = control;
    }

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue, String oldValue, String newValue) {
        erroneous.setValue(!newValue.matches(mask) || ((max_lenght > 0) ? newValue.length() > max_lenght : false) || newValue.length() == 0);
        control.setStyle( erroneous.get() ? STYLE : "-fx-effect: null;");
    }
}
```

using it within my controller like this:

```
field1.textProperty().addListener(new InputMaskChecker(InputMaskChecker.DATASOURCE, field1));
field2.textProperty().addListener(new InputMaskChecker(InputMaskChecker.TEXTONLY, field2));
field3.textProperty().addListener(new InputMaskChecker(InputMaskChecker.PASSWORD, field3));
field4.textProperty().addListener(new InputMaskChecker(InputMaskChecker.NUMERIC, 1, field4));
```

It works as expected with a glitch: I'd like to have my SAVE button on the main controller react to listeners in a way that it is disabled if a field has an error.

**It now comes my brainstorming request.** Have you got any suggestion?

Using a shared `SimpleBooleanProperty`, AND-ing listeners wouldn't obviously work.

**(solution) UPDATE:**
Add a `private final BooleanBinding binding;` variable to the Controller. Then:

```
InputMaskChecker listener1 = new InputMaskChecker(InputMaskChecker.DATASOURCE, field1);
InputMaskChecker listener2 = new InputMaskChecker(InputMaskChecker.DATASOURCE, field2);
InputMaskChecker listener3 = new InputMaskChecker(InputMaskChecker.DATASOURCE, field3);
InputMaskChecker listener4 = new InputMaskChecker(InputMaskChecker.DATASOURCE, field4);

field1.textProperty().addListener(listener1);
field2.textProperty().addListener(listener2);
field3.textProperty().addListener(listener3);
field4.textProperty().addListener(listener4);

binding = new BooleanBinding() {
    {
    super.bind(listener1.erroneous, listener2.erroneous, listener3.erroneous, listener4.erroneous);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean computeValue() {
        return (listener1.erroneous.get() || listener2.erroneous.get() || listener3.erroneous.get() || listener4.erroneous.get());
    }
};

control.getDisableProperty().bind(binding);
```

Done ;)

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest next approache:

Make you `InputMaskChecker` stateful with `public SimpleBooleanProperty valid;` which will be referred in update method:

```
@Override
public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue, String oldValue, String newValue) {
    valid.set(!newValue.matches(mask) || ((max_lenght > 0) ? newValue.length() > max_lenght : false) || newValue.length() == 0);
    // BTW, I would suggest to use styleclasses instead for performance reasons
    control.setStyle( valid.get() ? STYLE : "-fx-effect: null; ):
}
```

then you can say in "Save" button creation:

```
Button btn = new Button("Save");
btn.disableProperty().bind(
      listener1.valid.and(listener2.valid).and(listener3.valid).not());
```

or create an utility method which will add listener and update "Save" disabled property.

Comment: Solved with low-level binding.
Anyway you can't use styleclasses with this. I tried but, once added a styleclass, it doesn't remove it afterwards...even using the `.setEffect(new Dropshadow(...));` method doesn't work.
The only chance is `control.setStyle( valid.get() ? STYLE : "-fx-effect: null; );`

Comment: setEffect() is expected to don't work. setStyle() has most priority in styles commands chain. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333985/javafx-can-not-set-font-size-programmatically-after-font-being-set-by-css/12334881#12334881

Comment: as you solved issue another way, please, post your code as a separate answer and accept your own answer instead of mine.

Comment: Well, it was another implementation but I followed your suggestion, your way.
I will, anyway, keep that in mind for the future. Thanks for both the help and the tip