# JavaFX FadeTransition conflicting with CSS -fx-opacity

Tags: css, animation, javafx-2, fadein, conflict

Im building a custom composite UI Control in JavaFX with a button, that should fade in from 0 to 0.1 opacity if hovering somewhere over the Control. If hovering over the button itself, opacity should change to 1.0, which can easily be achieved via CSS.

Here the FadeTransition:

```
// unfortunately, animations cannot be defined in CSS yet
FadeTransition fadeInButton =
    new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(300), settingsButton);
fadeInButton.setFromValue(0);
fadeInButton.setToValue(0.1);
```

And here the CSS for the button:

```css
.settings-button {
    -fx-background-image: url("settings_32_inactive.png");
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    -fx-background-position: center center;
    -fx-opacity: 0; /* button shall be initially invisible, will be faded in */
}

.settings-button:hover {
    -fx-background-image: url("settings_32.png");
    -fx-opacity: 1.0; /* why is this ignored if used together with animations? */
}
```

Both animation and CSS properties work great separately. Unfortunately, in combination, the animation seems to override the -fx-opacity property in the CSS file. Any ideas how to make both animation and CSS properties work together?

Comment: Just a suggestion, why not to use the same fade animation to fade 1.0 on the mouse over event of the button.

Comment: This would probably work, but I would like to do as much as possible via CSS (way easier to change, even in production, no re-compile,...).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have css over API call, see next topic: [JavaFX: Cannot set font size programmatically after font being set by CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333985/javafx-can-not-set-font-size-programmatically-after-font-being-set-by-css/12334881#12334881)

But you can do next trick:

- Have button with opacity 0.1 unhovered and 1 if hovered
- Put button into Pane and animate this pane from 0 to 1

See next css:

```css
/*Button*/
.b1 { -fx-opacity: 0.1; }
.b1:hover { -fx-opacity: 1.0; }
/*Pane*/
.p1 {
    -fx-border-color: red;
    -fx-opacity: 0;
}
```

and code:

```
public class OpacityCss extends Application {

    private static final Duration DURATION = Duration.millis(300);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.getStyleClass().add("p1");
        pane.setMinSize(100, 100);
        pane.setMaxSize(100, 100);

        final Button btn = new Button("Fading Button");
        btn.getStyleClass().add("b1");
        pane.getChildren().add(btn);

        final FadeTransition fade = new FadeTransition(DURATION, pane);
        fade.setAutoReverse(true);
        fade.setFromValue(0);
        fade.setToValue(1);

        pane.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                fade.setCycleCount(1); // this way autoreverse wouldn't kick
                fade.playFromStart();
            }
        });

        pane.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                fade.setCycleCount(2); // starting from autoreverse
                fade.playFrom(DURATION);
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().addAll(pane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/css/btn.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(); }
}
```

Comment: Nice trick, thank you! But in the topic you are pointing me to, it says that API calls *may* be overridden by user CSS, doesn't it?