# JavaFX MouseEvent not firing inside ScrollPane (above ~15 pixels)

Tags: events, javafx, mouse, padding, scrollpane

### Original Question

*Progress to answer below*

I want to have some *thumbnails* inside a `ScrollPane`. The thumbnails highlight when you mouse-over them.

The problem is, unless I apply `scrollPane.setPadding(new Insets(15,0,0,0));`, the listeners I have applied, (as well as the listeners for other controls such as Buttons) **DO NOT FIRE**. They only fire if the mouse is ~**15 pixels** below the top edge of the ScrollPane.

**A.** Shows no padding applied. *(Red area shows approximate listener firing zone)*

[image: No Padding, Not Firing]

**B.** Shows 15px padding applied.

[image: 15px Padding, Firing]

I was constantly clicking in both images. The Buttons only respond below ~15px too.
So unless I have padding, you cannot interact with any controls along the top, buttons, labels etc.

How can I get around this, please?

**The scrollPane is constructed by:**

```
    parentStage = stage;
    parentScene = scene;
    mainStyle = mS;
    backgroundStyle = bS;
    highlightBackgroundStyle = hBS;
    selectionPanelRoot.setCenter(selectionScroller);
    selectionPanelRoot.setBottom(bottomButtons);
    bottomButtons.setLeft(generalButtons);
    bottomButtons.setRight(moreButtons);
    selectionScroller.setContent(selectionContent);
    selectionContent.setPrefWrapLength(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    selectionContent.setHgap(10);
    selectionContent.setVgap(10);
    //selectionContent.setPadding(new Insets(15,0,0,0)); //<-- Uncomment to achieve what is shown in Image B.
    selectionScroller.setMinHeight(280);
    selectionScroller.setPrefSize(Double.MAX_VALUE , Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

**The thumbnails consist of:**

```
    mediaPanel = mSP;
    parentStage = stage;
    parentScene = scene;
    mainStyle = mS;
    backgroundStyle = bS;
    highlightBackgroundStyle = hBS;
    

    root.setPrefSize(100, 140);
    //root.setOpaqueInsets(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    root.setTop(topInfoRow);
    root.setCenter(view);
    root.setBottom(keySelector);
    
    topInfoRow.setLeft(timeLabel);
    topInfoRow.setCenter(testButton);
    topInfoRow.setRight(closeButton);
    closeButton.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

    
    closeButton.setGraphic(closeButtonView);
    view.setVisible(true);
    view.setFitWidth(130);
    view.setFitHeight(100);

    
    
    
    keySelector.setEditable(false);
    keySelector.setFocusTraversable(false);
    keySelector.setText("No Key");
```

---

### Progress

I have made a bit of progress with answering this question.

The `scrollPane` is actually added to a `BorderPane` layout, right in the "Centre". By default, there are margins between components in the BorderPane (***I don't know how to change this!***). But if I simply add in something to the "Top" of the BorderPane, the problem is resolved.

**The BorderPane Layout:**

[image: BorderPane Layout]

Seemingly, adding something in the top *pushes down* the `scrollPane`by the ~15 pixels which are causing the problem. So it's as if originally the `scrollPane` was occupying the area at the "Top" which it shouldn't have been doing so.

**After Adding some Text to the "Top"**

[image: After Adding some Text to the "Top"]

Comment: It's really difficult to reproduce your problem based only on the images and the few lines of incomplete code you show. Could you please provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hi @JoséPereda I appreciate your request for an MVCE, however I am struggling to create one! I have however, got a step closer to solving this, and I am going to update the question. Feel free to have a look at my findings.

Answer (score 0):

(This is a longshot but I'm assuming you're looking for clues, rather than a fixed code - since you went for screenshots rather than MCVE, as others say.)

I would look outside your scrollPane code, at how the scene is set up and how java code and CSS interact (ifterfere?). Padding is set by both Java code and CSS. Even if you don't set CSS there appears to be some predefined styling applied by the browser.

See this, for example: 
[JavaFX: Cannot set font size programmatically after font being set by CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333985/javafx-cannot-set-font-size-programmatically-after-font-being-set-by-css)
(Sergey Grinev's answer)

> The JavaFX CSS implementation applies the following order of precedence; a style from a user agent style sheet has lower priority than a value set from code, which has lower priority than a Scene or Parent style sheet. Inline styles have highest precedence.