# How to style FontAwesomeIconView using stylesheets .css? JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, font-awesome

I have following code:

```
private Hyperlink hyperlink = new Hyperlink();
private FontAwesomeIconView fontawesome = new FontAwesomeIconView(FontAwesomeIcon.TIMES);
hyperlink.setGraphic(fontawesome);
```

And now i have problem. I need to change css of my FontAwesome icon dynamically. So i need to use stylesheet instead of using method like:

```
fontawesome.setScaleX(0.65);
fontawesome.setScaleY(0.65);
fontawesome.setTranslateX(-1.0);
fontawesome.setFill(Color.WHITE);
```

I tried something like that:

```
.root {
    -icons-color: red;
}

.glyph-icon {
    -fx-font-family: "FontAwesome";
    -icons-color: red;
}
```

but it is not working :(
Anyone can tell me how i can style my icons inside css file?

Comment: Try removing " " and it will look like -fx-font-family: FontAwesome;

Comment: As well as the above fix, see this answer for ideas how to implement setStyle to change font size ---  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12334881/3625077

Answer (score 1):

Well my fix was something like that:

```
.glyph-icon {
    -fx-fill: #b45959;
}
```

i just need to use -fx-fill to change color instead of -icons-color